# Can lazy susan's handle moment loads? If so, how to determine the magnitude of moment load it can take?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings

Can lazy susan's like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001GTCB7Y) or [this](https://www.revolutionindustrial.com.au/lazy-susan-bearing-12-inch-305mm-455-kg-load-made) handle moment loads? If so, how to determine the magnitude of moment load it can take?

I've searched online but couldn't find anything on whether the bearings of the type linked above can handle moment loads, only balanced load (which I think is equivalent to axial load) is given.

Comment: Many will only handle compression and not tension.  In such cases just use two (facing each other) so that each one handles the load in compression.  Moment capability of such would likely be comparable  (proportional)to axial force applied at bearing.

Comment: explain what you mean by a moment load.  A moment of about the rotation axis will make it spin.  A moment perpendicular to that will eventally turn it over.  If you want to fasten it to a base and then try to tip it over, its ability to withstand it will be based on how it's made.  Certainly you could make one with industrial bearings that could stop a truck.

Comment: @TigerGuy By moment load I basically mean [this](https://www.silverthin.com/news/articles/images/wait-a-moment1.png). The sort of load that would try to displace the two rings through rotation.

Comment: @Abel I want to start off by saying I'm not a mechanical engineer. How will stacking two lazy susan bearings solve the tension issue? Can you illustrate your point in some way, perhaps through a diagram?

Comment: I suggest reading up.  https://www.motionsolutions.com/products/mechanical/rotary-bearings/ does a good job in at least listing bearings.  Image search "angular contact bearing" for numerous images of a pair of ball bearings in a similar configuration to what I'm talking about.